# How to use "Alt Gr" in xbindkeys?

Tags: ubuntu, xbindkeys

I cant figure out the code to use <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> in `xbindkeys`.
I tried `ISO_Level3_Shift`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using a US keyboard layout by any chance?

Answer (score 4):

To get the code of a key, run `xbindkeys --key` in the terminal, and you'll get a window where you get the codes of the buttons you press.

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]!  **;-)** An edit and an upvote.  For future reference, please [edit] your answer and provide the output for [Alt Gr].